# How to read unread emails with the Gmail API (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, discord, gmail-api

I'm creating a bot that will take emails sent to a specific account and push them to a discord server. I found the Gmail API. How would I be able to find unread emails, and mark them as read once operated on?

Comment: Are you trying to SEND email or READ email?

Comment: Currently, what I am asking for is to read emails. I need emails to be instantly picked up and added to an array. Having a send feature in the future would be nice, however.

Comment: You should check out the gmail API.

Comment: Here's a browser API: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/reference.md

Comment: Thank you! I believe this will suit my needs.

Comment: Actually, as I am looking through the docs, I don't see any way to automatically detect a new email that has been received. Is this possible with the Gmail API, and if so how would I go about this?

Comment: I have no idea, I've never used it, I just see that it exists. You could just poll periodically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gmail API does not instantly detect if a new email has arrived. However, you can trigger a script to check for unread emails from a certain sender.

For example:

```
var newEmails = Gmail.Users.Threads.list("me", {"q":"is:unread from:email"});
//do stuff with them
```

Then iterate through the threads and remove the `unread` label from them to not repeat them in the next search:

```
for (var i = 0; i < newEmails.threads.length; i++){
      var threadId = newEmails.threads[i].id;
      Gmail.Users.Threads.modify({"removeLabelIds":["UNREAD"]}, "me", threadId);
    }
```

If you are using Apps Script, create a Trigger to run the function every x minutes or hours in Edit > Current Project Triggers.

References:

- [Gmail API List](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list)
- [Gmail API Modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/modify)
- [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

Comment: You say from a certain sender. Does this mean that it can only be used with specific email addresses?

Comment: @ProgrammerPlays No, actually you can do [complex searches](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190), just like the ones you can do in the Gmail interface search bar.